# Precision Agriculture using IOT System

Tags: agriculture

Before asking my agriculture related question I would like to give some context being from an engineering background .

Today Internet of Things (IOT) and Embedded firmware/hardware modules revolutionized innovation in many sectors including agriculture in what is  called Precision Agriculture where every input attribute to the plant environment like nutrients concentration pattern over time and wave length and intensity of light pattern over time can be implemented and controlled and automated precisely using IOT controlled fluid/nutrient pumps and led of different wave lengths and all that can
be real time monitored and controlled as well.

Now, my questions related to agriculture:

Is there some standard numerical tabular or graphical data about concentration patterns, light wave length patterns, rules that relate the quality, standard nutritional and chemical facts of the final fruit/vegetable to these patterns from a plant biochemical perspective so that if these patterns are implemented using such IOT system the quality and measured nutrition facts of the final fruit or vegetable can be tailored to meet specific requirement for the final crop?

Second Question, what is the name of the field studying that and how to get such numerical data if exist?

Comment: Please consider rewriting your first question so that it is less long winded & easier to read. As originally written it contained 89 words & there was no punctuation. Please respect your readers, we need to breath! I have made some changes, but it is still excessively long winded. Keeping things simple is always best. Also, could you please explain what you mean by "concentration patterns".

Comment: @Fred Sorry for the formatting , thanks for editing and what I meant by concentration patterns is values of concentration of nutrients that changes over time , is there rules that manage the relationships between how concentration change overtime and the final nutrition facts of the fruit or vegetable . Thanks for pointing that formatting notice to me .